# How to check for isBrowser in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In the past you could use `isBrowser` from Angular Universal to check if your page was rendering in a browser (and therefore you can use things like localStorage) or if it was doing server side pre-rendering.

But it seems that `angular2-universal` was dissolved into `@angular/core`, `@angular/platform-server` and `@angular/platform-browser`.

I've looked for similar functionality in the API documentation for Angular 4 and also tried to find it somewhere in the source code, but without luck.

Am I missing something or what is the Angular 4 way of checking if the rendering is running in a browser? Or should I simply just check if `window` is defined?

Comment: isPlatformBrowser()  -    https://stackoverflow.com/a/43619639/7974050

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error using isBrowser function in angular universal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43586005/error-using-isbrowser-function-in-angular-universal)

Answer (score 31):

```
import { PLATFORM_ID, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser} from '@angular/common';
...
export class MyComponent {
...
    testBrowser: boolean;
    constructor(
        @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) platformId: string) {
            this.testBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(platformId);
            if (this.testBrowser) {
                //this is only executed on the browser
            }
    }
...
```

Answer (score 3):

You can import `isPlatformBrowser(<platform id>)` as so:

```
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
```

and that will allow you to check for whether it is rendering in browser or not.

As a note, there is also a `isPlatformServer` in `@angular/common` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do the Following steps:

```
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
import { Inject, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core;

constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) platformId: Object){
  const isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId);
}
```

I hope it helps: