# Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices Captures RxJS IntervalObservable During Angular OnInit

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core, rxjs

I'm attempting to initiate repeated client-side action within `OnInit` of an Angular 4 component using an `IntervalObservable`. The application uses ASP.NET Core.

The observable subscription is executed. However, server-side prerendering in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices` appears to be executing the subscription -- never returning the rendered page to the browser.

What am I doing wrong here? Below are the steps to reproduce. In this sample I'm just trying to `console.log` a heartbeat in the browser.

## Steps to reproduce

1. Create and `cd` into a new directory.
2. Run `dotnet new angular`.
3. Run `npm install`.
4. Replace the contents of `ClientApp/app/components/home/home.component.ts` with the code snippet below.
5. Run `dotnet run` and go to http://localhost:5000.

```ts
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { IntervalObservable } from "rxjs/observable/IntervalObservable";

    @Component({
        selector: 'home',
        templateUrl: './home.component.html'
    })
    export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
        ngOnInit(): void {
            IntervalObservable.create(1500).subscribe((iteration:number)=>console.log(iteration));
        }
    }
```

When the request comes in, the debug console begins reporting the `iteration`, as shown in the code snippet. The page renderer times out and eventually return an error page, but the `IntervalObservable` subscription continues to iterate in the debug console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a resolution using the technique shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/46893433/402726.

Essentially, we use the `platform` functions provided Angular to determine if we're executing in the browser and, if so, run the in-browser heartbeat.

Below is an updated form of the question snippet implementing the fix.

```ts
import { PLATFORM_ID, Component, Inject, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { isPlatformBrowser } from "@angular/common";
import { IntervalObservable } from "rxjs/observable/IntervalObservable";

@Component({
    selector: "home",
    templateUrl: "./home.component.html"
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    private isRunningInBrowser: boolean;
    constructor( @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) platformId: string) {
        this.isRunningInBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(platformId);
    }
    public ngOnInit(): void {
        if (!this.isRunningInBrowser) return;
        IntervalObservable.create(1000).subscribe(() => console.log("on an interval"));
    }
}
```