# Angular 8 universal window is not defined

Tags: angular, angular-universal

Noob(almost) here!

I have an Angular application which is based on `"@angular/core": "^8.2.14",` and it is CSR (Client-Side Rendering).
Now I want to switch it to SSR (Server-side rendering).

I have done step by step of [Angular documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/10.0.x/docs/documentation/stories/universal-rendering.md) , but my application can't find window object, I have searched many websites for the solution, this is my final server.ts file below, but my app cant find window, and sometimes other packages like SVG!

```
// These are important and needed before anything else
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';

import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';

import * as express from 'express';
import {join} from 'path';

// Faster server renders w/ Prod mode (dev mode never needed)
enableProdMode();

// Express server
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');

const domino = require('domino');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
// index from browser build!
const template = fs.readFileSync(path.join('.', 'dist', 'browser', 'index.html')).toString();
// for mock global window by domino
const win = domino.createWindow(template);
// mock
global['window'] = win;
// not implemented property and functions
Object.defineProperty(win.document.body.style, 'transform', {
    value: () => {
        return {
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true,
        };
    },
});
// mock documnet
global['document'] = win.document;
// othres mock
global['CSS'] = null;
// global['XMLHttpRequest'] = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest;
global['Prism'] = null;

// * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
const {AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP} = require('./dist/metronic-server/main');

// Express Engine
import {ngExpressEngine} from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
// Import module map for lazy loading
import {provideModuleMap} from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
    providers: [
        provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
    ]
}));

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'));

// TODO: implement data requests securely
app.get('/api/*', (req, res) => {
    res.status(404).send('data requests are not supported');
});

// Server static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser')));

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    global['navigator'] = {userAgent: req['headers']['user-agent']} as Navigator;
    res.render('index', {req});
});

// Start up the Node server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Node server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

but I still have error:
[image]

How can I fix this error?

Many thanks.

Comment: After fixing this error, I will get SVG is not defined! You know I used packages which are not supported by Angular SSR, I mean is there any other way not to checking isPlatformBrowser support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Angular Universal is server side rendered, there is no window object server side. This means you either need to mock the window object away like [here](https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/1523) in your `server.ts` file:

```
const domino = require('domino');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const templateA = fs
.readFileSync(path.join('.', 'dist', 'index.html'))
.toString();
const win = domino.createWindow(templateA);
win.Object = Object;
win.Math = Math;

win.navigator.language = 'en';

global['Event'] = null;
global['window'] = win;
global['document'] = win.document;
global['branch'] = null;
global['object'] = win.object;
global['localStorage'] = localStorage;
global['sessionStorage'] = sessionstorage;
global['navigator'] = win.navigator ;
```

or wrap every occurance of `window.*` inside your Angular files with an

```
if (isPlatformBrowser(platformId)) {
  window.*
}
```

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46099644/how-to-check-for-isbrowser-in-angular-4)

Comment: After fixing this error, I will get SVG is not defined! You know I used packages which are not supported by Angular SSR, I mean is there any other way not to checking isPlatformBrowser support?

Comment: Which package are you using that is causing this error? And what is the exact error message?

Comment: I'm using apecxchart for angular, inside of it, it is using https://svgjs.com/docs/3.0/, but the problem is not limited to this package, because after solving this, another package might cause an error of undefined.